# Help me to recover from grub rescue prompt

Tags: grubrescue

I had ubuntu and windows 7 dual boot
now i **formatted the whole hdd and installed only kubuntu**
the bootloader I installed in

**sda1 /boot 500mb**

but now i'm stuck in grub rescue prompt
now what to do?

Answer (score 0):

GRUB should have been installed to the drive, i.e. `/dev/sda`.

First, you need to boot into your system. This can be achieved in many different ways, for the sake of simplicity I will cover only one.

1. Download [Super Grub2 Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/) and burn it to CD (or USB key)
2. Boot the newly created medium
3. Select the *Everything* option
4. You should see a list of options similar to this one:

   [image: Super Grub2 disk screenshot]

   Use the arrow keys to select the first *Linux* option and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

If everything goes well, you should have started your Ubuntu system. Now it's time to repair it. Here's how:

1. Install GRUB on the main drive:

   ```
   sudo grub-install /dev/sda
   ```
2. Rebuilding the menu should not be necessary, but just in case:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
3. Reboot and check if GRUB shows up

Answer (score 0):

Download and burn the [Boot-Repair CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) (you can also create a bootable flash drive). Boot from it. It will automatically open a program in Lubuntu environment. The program will give you instructions for repairing GRUB.